# reset checkbox by ID

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I have hundreds of checkboxes in a VBox need to be reset from a "Reset" button.

How do I convert "p1" into a checkbox component?

```
function private resetChk():void {
    CheckBox("p"+"1" as CheckBox).selected = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
private function resetChk():void
{
    CheckBox(this["p"+i]).selected = false;
}
```

Where **this** is the parent of the CheckBox's and **i** is the checkbox number.

Maybe better of just putting all your CheckBox's into an array and doing:

```
var i:CheckBox;
for each(i in checkBoxArray)
{
    i.selected = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the get all chilred method, check if a child is instnace of checkbox, if it is, typecast into a checkbox and reset the value.

e.g assume myVBox is the component, then do the following

```
for each(child:DisplayObject in myVBox.getAllChildren())
{
    if(child is checkBox)
    {
       var checkBox:CheckBox = (child as Checkbox);
       checkBox.selected = false;
    }
}
```

I have not run the code and tested, but im pretty sure that the above will work robustly, there could be some typos though, but this is the best solution to solve a problem like yours.